# jquery search with json array

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have the following jquery function, its supposed to be a simple search. It is not working. Can some one tell what is wrong with it and how to fix it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var a  =[
        {"name":"mynewname", "id" : "t2", "location" : "India"},
        {"name":"mynewname1", "id" : "t21", "location" : "China"},    
    ];

jQuery('#search-json-submit').click(function() {
    jQuery('#search-output').html('');
    var search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
    var search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*"+search_query+".*", "g");
    jQuery.each(a, function(k, v) {
        if(v['name'].match(search_query_regex) ||
           v['id'].match(search_query_regex) ||
           v['location'].match(search_query_regex)) {
               jQuery('#search-output').append('<li>Search results found in: '+'{ name:       "'+v['name']+'", id: "'+v['id']+'", location: "'+v['location']+'" } </li>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="search-json-input" />
<input type="button" id="search-json-submit" value="search" />
<h4>Search Results</h4>
<ol id="search-output">

</ol>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files 
        as needed -->
  <script src="boot/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I cant figure out what is wrong and why it is not working. please help

**EDIT**

I did as u said, here what the script look like now,

```
<script>

var a  =[
{"name":"mynewname", "id" : "t2", "location" : "India"},
{"name":"mynewname1", "id" : "t21", "location" : "China"},    
];
$(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery('#search-json-submit').click(function() {
jQuery('#search-output').html('');
var search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
var search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*"+search_query+".*", "g");
jQuery.each(a, function(k, v) {
    if(v['name'].match(search_query_regex) ||
       v['id'].match(search_query_regex) ||
       v['location'].match(search_query_regex)) {
           jQuery('#search-output').append('<li>Search results found in: '+'{ name:         "'+v['name']+'", id: "'+v['id']+'", location: "'+v['location']+'" } </li>');
    }
});
});
});
</script>
```

still does not work

Comment: You need to put your dom bindings inside of a `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: Also, don't link to the jquery source file more than once.

Comment: can you give me an example? m not sure how. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Bind your DOM handlers inside of a `$(document).ready(function() {});` block. This ensures the DOM has been created before trying to bind handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#search-json-submit').click(function() {
        jQuery('#search-output').html('');
        var search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
        var search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*"+search_query+".*", "g");
        jQuery.each(a, function(k, v) {
            if(v['name'].match(search_query_regex) ||
               v['id'].match(search_query_regex) ||
               v['location'].match(search_query_regex)) {
                   jQuery('#search-output').append('<li>Search results found in: '+'{ name:       "'+v['name']+'", id: "'+v['id']+'", location: "'+v['location']+'" } </li>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could put your javascript code just **before** the **closing** body tag which does effectively the same thing.

Also -- delete this line:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

You are already including JQuery at the top of your page, no need to load it again

Comment: Make sure you get rid of the duplicate jquery library you are including

Comment: i updated including my script. i did as you said, still no working

Comment: @LahiruTjay if that's the case then you have an issue elsewhere in your script. If you look at the jsfiddle I created (based on your code) everything works fine. Do you have any errors in your javascript console? - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging